# Using Fragments and Sherlock and going bug in version 4.0

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

Well guys, I'm using the lib Sherlock and implemented a fragment that is functioning without problem in version 2.3 of the android, but as I run it on an android version 4.0 with the `NullPointerException` error happens, and someone could help, I am new to programming for android.
My class and the [error][1] is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//         Getting an instance of action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        
//        // Enabling Tab Navigation mode for this action bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
//        
//        // Enabling Title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
//        
//        // Creating Android Tab
        Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText("Android")
                            .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<AndroidFragment>(this, "android", AndroidFragment.class) )
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.android);
//        
//        // Adding Android Tab to acton bar
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
//        
        // Creating Apple Tab
        Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Apple")
                .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<AppleFragment>(this, "apple", AppleFragment.class))
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apple);

        // Adding Apple Tab to action bar
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);        
//        
//        // Orientation Change Occurred
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            int currentTabIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("apple");
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(currentTabIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        int currentTabIndex = getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex();
        outState.putInt("tab_index", currentTabIndex);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}



 logcat in text format



06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtabwithimages/in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtabwithimages.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtabwithimages.CustomTabListener.onTabSelected(CustomTabListener.java:32)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper$TabWrapper.onTabSelected(ActionBarWrapper.java:338)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:512)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:441)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:427)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper.addTab(ActionBarWrapper.java:371)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarsherlocknavtabwithimages.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
06-06 04:33:00.496: E/AndroidRuntime(619):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please add the full logcat as text to this question - that is at least the full stacktrace including any "caused by" stacks.

Comment: hi  Wolfram Rittmeyer put the image of the logcat, this period saw the error occurs in this comparison,
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            int currentTabIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("apple");
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(currentTabIndex);
        }

 but still can not think of another way of setting SelectedNavigationItem. Already required.

Comment: For the future: Really do post the logcat as text. And **add all of the exception**. Your screenshot ends where the interesting stuff begins.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your `savedInstanceState` does not contain a value for the key "apple". Do it like this instead:

```
int currentTabIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("apple", 0);
```

In this case the default is used and you do not get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: hi Wolfram Rittmeyer, I tried the way I started, but now the error occurs in line 31 where it is added to tab1. The logcat is below code in text format and full excuse for putting a piece missing.

Comment: This new error happens in your onTabSelected() method - which is not included in the sources. It actually is a *new* question, because I answered your first one. It just happens to be a NullPointerException again - would be nice to accept the answer and open a new question! And add the correct code. You might link to the new question here, so that I will get a notification about it.